# How do bungs semantically relate to eyes?

Tags: étymologie

I'm assuming Etymonline signifies "A stopper for closing a hole in a container" for bung. But I can't think of any semantic relationship between bungs and eyes! Their functions and purposes differ. Bungs can be easily removed, but human eyes aren't supposed to be. Undeniably, eyes aren't designed to close holes!

[image]

> [ullage (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ullage#etymonline_v_4441)
>
> "amount by which a cask or bottle falls short of being full," late 15c., from Anglo-French *ulliage* (early 14c.), Anglo-Latin *oliagium* (late 13c.), Old French *ouillage*, from *ouiller* "to fill up (a barrel) to the bung," literally "to fill to the eye," from *ueil* "eye" (**perhaps used colloquially for "bung"**), from Latin *oculus* (from PIE root [*okw-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*okw-) "to see").

Comment: L'œil est un trou qui laisse passer la lumière à l'intérieur du corps humain, ou de tout autre conteneur, l'œil se ferme par la paupière, celui du conteneur par un clapet ou un bouchon … « Élémentaire mon cher Watson ! », phrase formulée lorsque l'énigme est résolue :-)

Comment: In the entries your refer to you can find something like "Transferred to the cask-mouth itself", and maybe therein lies part of the answer, it's about metonymy. If you see an eye like you do a mouth it helps too ;-) I

Comment: @AmandeAdorable … non, non, trouvez donc les anus de chaque œil et une rétine dans la bouche :-) … il s'agit de lumière pour les yeux et non de liquide ou aliment qui rentrent par là, et si vous marchez en ouvrant la bouche et  fermant les yeux au bord d'un précipice, votre conclusion … Vous ne voyez pas l'extérieur en ouvrant la bouche. Un œil de bœuf sur les toits, l'œil technique, c'est la capacité d'un tuyau à laisser passer un flux de lumière, et qui dit flux dit liquide, ce qui induit le goulot, ou le très petit orifice du conteneur.

Comment: @Personne C'est simplement qu'en anglais le mot _mouth_ apparaît dans des composés comme _cask-mouth_  où il tient lieu de l'_oeil_ qu'on aurait en français. C'est une des raisons qui explique qu'on ait de la difficulté à voir le lien avec l'oeil dans la question...